# How to send data from Matlab to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, web-services, matlab

I'm very new to Rails and web development.

I'm generating a bunch of objects in Matlab and I'd like send these objects to a database in my Rails app.  Can anyone advise me on how to do this?

So far, on the Rails end, I've generated basic scaffolding for my data. I can add objects to my database using a form at '/myobjects/new'.

On the Matlab end, I've been trying to add objects using HTTP POST requests, like so:

```
s = urlread('http://localhost:3000/myobjects.json','POST',{'myobject','{name1:''value1''}'})
```

This fails and prints the following to the Rails console:

```
Started POST "/myobjects.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-16 11:48:28 -0400
Processing by MyobjectsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"myobject"=>"{name1:'value1'}"}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `stringify_keys' for "{name1:'value1'}":String):
  app/controllers/myobjects_controller.rb:43:in `new'
  app/controllers/myobjects_controller.rb:43:in `create'
```

This approach might be way off base, but hopefully the code above makes my goal clear.  Can anyone tell me how to fix my code, or suggest a better strategy for getting my data into rails?

EDIT

At the moment my new and create methods look like this (but I can change them as required)

```
# GET /irs/new
  # GET /irs/new.json
  def new
    @ir = Ir.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @ir }
    end
  end

  # POST /irs
  # POST /irs.json
  def create
    @ir = Ir.new(params[:ir])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @ir.save
       format.html { redirect_to @ir, notice: 'Ir was successfully created.' }
       format.json { render json: @ir, status: :created, location: @ir }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @ir.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you post the new and create action your posting to?

Comment: Ok, see edit above.  Is that the info you were looking for?

Comment: Maybe use sprintf to create the name1: value1 pair and then send that string in?

Comment: @Ansari   Thanks, but no dice.  Did this in Matlab `s = urlread('http://localhost:3000/irs.json','POST',{'ir',sprintf('{%s:%s}','field1','value1')})`  and got this `NoMethodError (undefined method ``stringify_keys' for "{field1:value1}":String)`

Comment: JSON isn't my strong suit, but I think you have to enclose them in single or double quotes. So try '{"%s":"%s"}' instead.

Comment: @dB': I might be wrong, but doesn't JSON use double-quoted strings. Try the following request from MATLAB: `s = urlread('http://localhost:3000/myobjects.json','POST',{'myobject','{"name1":"value1"}'})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I gave up trying to do this with matlab's built-in functions.  Instead, I imported a Java library ([Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/)). Here's the script I came up with.  This did the job.

```
javaaddpath(['utils/httpcomponents-client-4.2/lib/httpcore-4.2.jar']);
javaaddpath(['utils/httpcomponents-client-4.2/lib/httpclient-4.2.jar']);


import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity


httpclient = DefaultHttpClient();

httppost = HttpPost('http://127.0.0.1:3000/myobjects.json');
httppost.addHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
httppost.addHeader('Accept','application/json');

params = StringEntity('{"field1":"value1"}');
httppost.setEntity(params);

response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Comment: Tried this with the 4.2 libs, but got the error <Java exception occurred: java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class> on the last line

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid that specific problem by setting

```
class MyobjectsController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery :except => :create
  ...
end
```

within your controller. It disables the CSRF token validity check.

Comment: Ok, this addition got rid of the CSRF warning but it didn't solve my problem.  I still get the NoMethodError and can't add objects to the database.  Thanks all the same though.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry. The problem is that you are transmitting `{'myobject','{name1:''value1''}'}`. Does Matlab support sending it like this: `{'myobject',{ 'name1', 'value1'}}`?

Comment: Yeah, I can do that, but I still get basically the same NoMethodError.  `"{name1:'value1'}":String` just becomes `"{'name1','value1'}":String`

Comment: You could `params[:ir] = JSON.parse(params[:ir])` before the Ir.new call (With the hash sent as you did orgiginally).

Comment: Hmm... tried that and I get a parser error: `JSON::ParserError (757: unexpected token at '{field1:'value1'}'):
  app/controllers/irs_controller.rb:50:in 'create'
`

Comment: That's because `{field1:'value'}` isn't valid JSON as far as the parser is concerned.  `field1` needs to be escaped by quotes.